# innerHTML of multiple elements with the same class name

Tags: python, selenium

```
def getElement(target, classname):
     driver = webdriver.Firefox()
     driver.get(target)
     element = driver.find_element_by_class_name(classname)
     time.sleep(5)
     contents = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
     driver.close()

     return contents

 print getElement("https://example.com", "originalposter")
```

I'm using selenium with Python, and I'm trying to get the innerHTML of multiple elements with the same classname. I thought my result would grab all the elements, and store them in a list, but it only grabs the first element and stores it.

How would I go about getting each element on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name(classname)
```

Finds elements by their class name instead of just an element...

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement